# c# web page to communicate with user machine's serial port

Tags: .net, serial-port, console-application

I have a website interface which is hosted at remote web IIS server.

When the user clicks on one button in the page, it needs to read some data from a device connected to client's local machine through serial port and display into the page if read successfully. As far as I understand, I can create a console application and install in client's local machine to read data, then I need a communication method from client's local machine to web server to display in the page.

At this point, I think I can save the data into database when console application is running, and then on website side, it can periodically make AJAX calls to retrieve data once the button is clicked.

But here is the problem: I need some mapping field to be stored in the database when console application was run, in order to tell website's AJAX call which data to retrieve and show in the page.

So far, I can think about two ways. One way is to pass one unique key (like session id or user id, etc) from website to console application to store in database, but I cannot find a way to make it work in this point since console application reads the input from command line.

The other way will be using some unique ID in the client's machine, like certain machine ID (or something else) which could be caught by both of local console application and web browser, but I do not really know what can be used at this point.

Thank you for reading my question, any help or idea will be appreciated.

P.S If this does not work out, I think I may have to create a separate windows application for all these matters.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured it out by looking up all the resources online for a few days.

1. Create a WCF Service Library to implement the method to communicate with Serial Port.
2. Create window service to host WCF Service, here is [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1009004/WCF-RESTful-on-Windows-Service-Host). Then you can access the WCF method to communicate with serial port using http.
3. On the web page, using javascript to send XMLHttpRequst to WCF Service. Here I'm having CORS issue since the web page is hosted in web server while WCF Service is hosted in local machine. I was stuck at this issue for a while and finally found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16039951/6362057).
4. Then the following is straightforward, when the serial port is opened by user clicking the button at web page, sending request to WCF service, it reads data, process it and save it into database by calling web API. While the web page is periodically sending request to retrieve data from database if there is any and then display in the page.

Update:

Instead of WCF Service, we can use [self-host Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written, my understanding is that you want to remotely call a method of a console application running on a client machine from your web server. You can do this in two ways:

- Host asp.net in your console application and give direct call from your web server to console application. Something as explained here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api
- Introduce a sevicebus pub-sub like Radis or MSMQ or one of the many others to send a message to console application when needed and then receive response from console application.

Comment: Thank you, @Deepark. I think I figured it out, i create a window service to host a WCF service in local machine, then browser side using javascript to  make XMLHttpRequest call WCF service, WCF service read and process data from local serial port and then call web api to save it into db.