# Self Hosting WCF inside WPF - Access-Control-Allow-Origin 405 error in Javascript request

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, wcf, self-hosting

I tried to do upload files from html page to self hosting WCF inside WPF application in local network.

Host like this:

```
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8200/GettingStarted/");
        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFUploader), baseAddress);
        try
        {
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWCFUploader), new WSHttpBinding(), "GettingStarted");
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            selfHost.Open();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
            selfHost.Abort();}
```

But, when I try to access http://localhost:8200/GettingStarted/ by Javascript, I have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin 405 Http Error.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross-origin resource sharing) configuration issue.

Your JS is probably not hosted on `localhost:8200` which requires you to add a specific HTTP header to allow for this XHR request.

This answer shall covert it all in details: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16039951/1503505