# 405 Method Not Allowed Wcf Service and Ionic

Tags: c#, wcf, cors

I am using wcf rest api to communicate with ionic app . While consuming rest api the console raised an error "405 Method not allowed". By searching google found there must be a "CORS error" .

Re Configured Wcf service by added the following lines inside Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }


        }
```

then i got

```
the 'access-control-allow-origin' header contains multiple values
```

I have also tried by adding an entry inside web.config file as below

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Now i see

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any Help

Comment: Please consider reading - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16039951/4792175

Answer (score 1):

i guess i now the problem. please use `*` in `[ServiceContract]`. like this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "*"
```

this way you allow your method receive options request.