# Access to WCF WebService from JavaScript - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, cross-domain, svc

I am using a WCF (.svc) WebService and it's working perfectly - I can call its methods without problems from Postman, PHP, etc. But, when I try to call it from **JavaScript/jQuery** using **AJAX**, there is an obvious problem - I do it from other domain than WS, so it won't let me do it.

It is all about POST methods. But there is a problem even when my page is sending firstly an OPTIONS method:

> OPTIONS ***'WS ADDRESS'*** 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ***'WS ADDRESS'*** Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. Origin ***'MY ADDRESS'*** is therefore not allowed
> access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

There are detailed responses:

[image: Responses]

Okay, I read about cross-domain and WS's Web.config contains all of it that is necessary (?)

[image: Web.config]

Please let me know what  am I doing wrong that I cannot reach my WS from JavaScript, even though it seems to me configured well. But still, it seems not to send these special headers in response... Thanks in advance.

Comment: That 405 code means your server’s configured to disallow OPTIONS requests. That’s what the *Method Not Allowed* message means. You must configure it to instead respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 or 204 success message & the right Access-Control-Allow-* headers. As far as how to do that, sounds like to you need to read more docs and study it further—start at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024347/cross-origin-resource-sharing-for-c-sharp-wcf-restful-web-service-hosted-as-wind/16039951#16039951 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911702/405-method-not-allowed-wcf-service-and-ionic

Answer (score 3):

[XML HttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) allows data to be transferred from a web server to the browser. The browsers, however, prevents [CORS](http://Cross-origin%20resource%20sharing) by default. 
GET request is not going to change anything on the server side (nothing is created/updated/deleted) - it's only going to return some data.

POST/PUT/DELETE requests, however, will process the request and change something on the server side and issue a response to the browser. If the response doesn't have a proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, the browser will block the response. But that doesn't matter because by the time the response is issued, the server has already processed the request and made changes, perhaps to a database.

In order to prevent POST/PUT/DELETE request to be processed on server side, browsers will send a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

A prefligth request is an http request with the method OPTIONS. So before sending the POST request, the browser will send an OPTIONS request with an additional header called `Access-Control-Request-Method` with the value of POST.

The `405 (Method Not Allowed)` error indicates the the server is not configured to accept OPTIONS request.

You can solve this issue either by using a wildcard for your web invoke method similar to this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*", UriTemplate = "/Path", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Or by adding an additional `[OperationContract]` to your `[ServiceContract]` that handles OPTIONS request similar to this:

```
 [OperationContract(Name = "OptionsMyFunction")]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "/Path", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement .NET IDispatchMessageInspector for this work.

- Create a class implementing `IDispatchMessageInspector`
- Create a class implementing  `Attribute,IEndpointBehavior,IOperationBehavior`

Allow only OPTIONS in your class implementing `IDispatchMessageInspector`

The code will look like this

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

namespace WapstyPrintService
{
    public class MessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        private ServiceEndpoint _serviceEndpoint;
        Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders;

        public MessageInspector(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
        {
            _serviceEndpoint = serviceEndpoint;
            requiredHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when an inbound message been received
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request">The request message.</param>
        /// <param name="channel">The incoming channel.</param>
        /// <param name="instanceContext">The current service instance.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The object used to correlate stateMsg. 
        /// This object is passed back in the method.
        /// </returns>
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request,
                                              IClientChannel channel,
                                              InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            var httpRequest = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request
            .Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
            return new
            {
                origin = httpRequest.Headers["Origin"],
                handlePreflight = httpRequest.Method.Equals("OPTIONS",
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called after the operation has returned but before the reply message
        /// is sent.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reply">The reply message. This value is null if the 
        /// operation is one way.</param>
        /// <param name="correlationState">The correlation object returned from
        ///  the method.</param>
        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            var state = (dynamic)correlationState;
            if (state.handlePreflight)
            {
                reply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "PreflightReturn");

                var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                reply.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, httpResponse);

                httpResponse.SuppressEntityBody = true;
                httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }

            var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
            foreach (var item in requiredHeaders)
            {
                httpHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace WapstyPrintService
{
    public class BehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IEndpointBehavior,
                                   IOperationBehavior
    {
        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
                                 BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        { }

        /// <summary>
        /// This service modify or extend the service across an endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="endpoint">The endpoint that exposes the contract.</param>
        /// <param name="endpointDispatcher">The endpoint dispatcher to be
        /// modified or extended.</param>
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
                                          EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            // add inspector which detects cross origin requests
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(
                                                   new MessageInspector(endpoint));
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
                                        ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        { }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription) { }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
                                          DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        { }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
                                        ClientOperation clientOperation)
        { }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription,
                                  BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        { }

    }
}
```

Then add your message inspector to service endpoint behavior

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(myService), _baseAddress);
foreach (ServiceEndpoint EP in host.Description.Endpoints)
            EP.Behaviors.Add(new BehaviorAttribute());
```